# WPF VisualStateManager Animation Binding

Tags: wpf, binding, visualstatemanager

I'm using a simple DoubleAnimation in Button.Trigger. Animation From is bound to root element ActualHeight. This works as expected.

Next I've tried to move the Storyboard to VisualStateManager. Now WPF complains:

System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=ActualWidth; DataItem=null; target element is 'DoubleAnimation' (HashCode=29201322); target property is 'To' (type 'Nullable`1')

Is it not possible to use bindings in animations within the VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups/VisualState ?

It seems not. I fixed the problem by moving the storyboard to resources. So now GameToTitle will work while TitleToGame will fail.

I'd still appreciate to know if this is expected or not.

Relevant XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainInterface">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="GameToTitle">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="GameScreenInterface" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(TranslateTransform.Y)" From="0" To="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=MainInterface}" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TitleScreenInterface" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(TranslateTransform.Y)" From="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=MainInterface, Converter={Converters:InverseConverter}}" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState x:Name="TitleScreenState" Storyboard="{StaticResource ResourceKey=GameToTitle}"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="GameScreenState">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="GameScreenInterface" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(TranslateTransform.Y)" From="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=MainInterface}" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TitleScreenInterface" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[1].(TranslateTransform.Y)" From="0" To="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, ElementName=MainInterface, Converter={Converters:InverseConverter}}" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <View:TitleScreen x:Name="TitleScreenInterface"/>
    <View:GameScreen x:Name="GameScreenInterface" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yes, you should provide some XAML.

Comment: Thanks but the issue is fixed now. I moved the storyboard to resources. Not sure why inline storyboard fails. (Just ignore the converter stuff - it just multiplies the value by -1 to get negative value)

Comment: The inline Storyboard fails because the VisualStates are not part of the logical tree, so any dependence on a logical tree (such as with bindings) will fail. I'm actually surprised it works when moving the Storyboards into local resources. Not sure I understand why, but I'll take it!

Comment: @KentBoogaart - I actually tested this approach and it doesn't seem to work. It does call the converter, but the property doesn't seem to be set. I don't know why it works for Goran.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the question's comments note, Storyboards containing bindings must be declared as resources instead of inline within the VisualStateGroup for the bindings to work. This is due to the fact that VisualStates aren't part of the VisualTree. Resources, on the other hand, are.

You can visualize this for yourself by using Snoop (or similar utility) to look at the visual tree of your application. You'll notice that Resources nodes appear in the visual tree within Snoop, but VisualStates do not.

[image: Storyboards appearing in the visual tree.]

Comment: Are those bindings supposed to work? Or is it just something that build? Basically is this the way you should create animations that need bindings on WPF?